# Why is port a string and not an integer?

Tags: http, go, port

The [`Port`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Port) method returns a string and not an integer. What is the reason for that and is it safe to prefix the port with ":"?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This is because what appears after the colon can be either a port number or service name.

The following is a valid example where the service name is used instead of a port number:

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:https") // port 443
// ...
```

The port mapping for a particular service can be looked up using [`net.LookupPort`](https://godoc.org/net#LookupPort). On Unix systems, the `/etc/services` file is sourced for the mappings.

Comment: I'm always intrigued by the open type/closed type dichotomy. I'd like to see something like a _mixed_ type where there are some defaults (here e.g. well-known ports and services) but also allows extending them, ultimately to support autocompletion. In my limited working knowledge TypeScripts ADTs come closest, maybe Swifts ADTs can express this also directly.

Answer (score 0):

For a number the default value is 0: if a function

```
 func (u * URL) Port () string
```

return number instead of sting the port will be 0

Port 0 is a reserved port in TCP/IP networking, meaning that it should not be used in TCP or UDP messages. However, port 0 carries special significance in network programming, particularly Unix socket programming: for requesting system-allocated, dynamic ports.

it is a need for programming in several functions

Comment: In libGURL, `url.port()` returns a string... but GURL also provides `url.has_port()`. So theoretically we could distinguish `http://example.com:/path` (has a port, but `port()` is empty-string) from `http://example.com/path` (doesn't have a port). Of course GURL itself doesn't do this! It even reports that `http://example.com:80/path` "doesn't have a port," on the grounds that the explicitly specified port is redundant with the scheme. Which is [crazy](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-jennings-http-srv-01.html), but never mind... Point is, `String` is not `Optional`. Don't conflate them.